# UnauthorizedAccessException when saving file, but can create a directory

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to save a file to the disk but I get UnauthorizedAccessException.
The error says I have to get the right permissions on the folder, and I've tried every possible user I can find but it doesn't work.

Tried the following users

- Network
- Network Services
- IUSR
- IUSR_[Computername]

And given the full rights without it working.

What I find really strange is that I create a directory before I try to save the file and that works perfectly, it's when trying to save a file to that new directory that I get the UnautorhizedAccessException.

The code is the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Images(HttpPostedFileBase file, string boatId)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + boatId));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            file.SaveAs(path);

        }
        return View($"Filen på {boatId} har laddats upp");
    }
```

Any ideas at what I'm missing?

Comment: You can try adding permissions to IIS_IUSRS user! Solves the issue for me by adding both IUSR and IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: @TeamKitsune Hi, still doesn't work with those users added and full rights for them. I'm using IIS Express if that changes anything.

Comment: Can you verify that whatever you are using as the Application Pool Identity is actually in the IIS_IUSERS group on the machine?

Comment: @TravisActon turns out I tried to save the path and not the file :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out what I was trying to do was saving the folder and not the file, I forgot to combine the fileName with the path.

Changed the Save part to the following:

```
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
```

Which solved the whole thing for me.