# UnauthorizedAccessException even though everything could be accessed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

so I my program keeps saying UnauthorizedAccessException even though we cleared the app from our antivirus/firewall. The error happens at this line:

```
FileStream log = File.Create(path);
```

It says I can't access the path. Below is the code in context.

```
  private void StartConversion1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        String path = Properties.Settings.Default.label;
        FileStream log = File.Create(path);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(log);
        foreach (String f in filesToProcess1)
        {
            // rest of the code
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44949026/1136211

Comment: Did you check that your program is running with the same user as you are ?

Comment: @Clemens THANK YOU

Comment: @bmtheo yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it is quiet evident that it is a permission issue

- Check if your app has sufficient permissions to write to the said Directory
- Remove the read-only attribute associated with the directory

  ```
  var di = new DirectoryInfo("Path to directory");
  di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
  ```

---

**Conclusion:**

```
    if(Directory.Exists(inputdirpath)) 
    {
    //Code to remove read-only attribute

    //Code to create File
    }
```